# Sql to join two foxpro tables

Tags: adodb, foxpro

I have two foxpro files as detailed below
E:\F1\Table1.dbf {Id, Name, Address, City}
E:\F2\Table2.dbf {Id, qualifcn, marks}

How can I join them to get an ADODB record set with details from both tables?

Thanks and regards

Jojy

Answer (score 0):

Like I have asked other people with similar questions - is this a One-time need or is this an On-going need?

For your general SQL syntax you might want to look at:
[Inner and Outer SQL Joins](http://www.datamartist.com/sql-inner-join-left-outer-join-full-outer-join-examples-with-syntax-for-sql-server)
Especially - **4) Full Outer Join SQL Example**

But if this is a one-time need, you can merely:

1. Manually create a new recipient table with ALL fields
2. Append Table1 into new table
3. Set relation to ID into Table2
4. REPLACE the recipient table's 'extra' fields with the Related Table2 values

After which your new recipient table has ALL field values from both tables.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I KNOW the following has worked with OleDB connection and same principal may work for you.  Since both your data components are on the same logical drive, just different paths, you might be able to via common root.

Instead of making a connection to your direct folder where the first data location is, make a connection to the common root path.  Then in your query, refer to the RELATIVE PATH to the tables

Connect to E:\

Your query could be

```
select
      T1.*,
      T2.*
   from
      F1\Table1 T1
         JOIN F2\Table2 T2
            on T1.ID = T2.ID
   where
      ...
```